# Função não pode ser usada em determinado escopo

Tags: javascript

Estou usando a seguinte biblioteca: [jQuery-Dual-Listbox](https://github.com/parvez/jQuery-Dual-Listbox).

Fiz uma simples modificação no código criando uma função que permitisse trabalhar com os elementos selecionados.

Nome da função: `afterChanges`

Segue o código da biblioteca modificada:

```js
/*
*       Developed by Justin Mead
*       ©2011 MeadMiracle
*  www.meadmiracle.com / meadmiracle@gmail.com
*       Version 1.3
*       Testing: IE8/Windows XP
*                Firefox/Windows XP
*                Chrome/Windows XP
*       Licensed under the Creative Commons GPL http://creativecommons.org/licenses/GPL/2.0/
*/

(function ($) {
    var settings = new Array();
    var group1 = new Array();
    var group2 = new Array();
    var onSort = new Array();
    $.configureBoxes = function (options) {
        var index = settings.push({
            box1View: 'box1View',
            box1Storage: 'box1Storage',
            box1Filter: 'box1Filter',
            box1Clear: 'box1Clear',
            box1Counter: 'box1Counter',
            box2View: 'box2View',
            box2Storage: 'box2Storage',
            box2Filter: 'box2Filter',
            box2Clear: 'box2Clear',
            box2Counter: 'box2Counter',
            to1: 'to1',
            allTo1: 'allTo1',
            to2: 'to2',
            allTo2: 'allTo2',
            transferMode: 'move',
            sortBy: 'text',
            useFilters: true,
            useCounters: true,
            useSorting: true,
            selectOnSubmit: true,
            afterChanges: function () { }
        })
        index--;
        $.extend(settings[index], options);
        group1.push({
            view: settings[index].box1View,
            storage: settings[index].box1Storage,
            filter: settings[index].box1Filter,
            clear: settings[index].box1Clear,
            counter: settings[index].box1Counter,
            index: index
        });
        group2.push({
            view: settings[index].box2View,
            storage: settings[index].box2Storage,
            filter: settings[index].box2Filter,
            clear: settings[index].box2Clear,
            counter: settings[index].box2Counter,
            index: index
        });
        if (settings[index].sortBy == 'text') {
            onSort.push(function (a, b) {
                var aVal = a.text.toLowerCase();
                var bVal = b.text.toLowerCase();
                if (aVal < bVal) { return -1; }
                if (aVal > bVal) { return 1; } return 0;
            });
        } else {
            onSort.push(function (a, b) {
                var aVal = a.value.toLowerCase();
                var bVal = b.value.toLowerCase();
                if (aVal < bVal) { return -1; }
                if (aVal > bVal) { return 1; } return 0;
            });
        } if (settings[index].useFilters) {
            $('#' + group1[index].filter).keyup(function () {
                Filter(group1[index]);
            });
            $('#' + group2[index].filter).keyup(function () {
                Filter(group2[index]);
            });
            $('#' + group1[index].clear).click(function () {
                ClearFilter(group1[index]);
            }); $('#' + group2[index].clear).click(function () {
                ClearFilter(group2[index]);
            });
        } if (IsMoveMode(settings[index])) {
            $('#' + group2[index].view).dblclick(function () {
                MoveSelected(group2[index], group1[index]);
                settings[index].afterChanges();
            });
            $('#' + settings[index].to1).click(function () {
                MoveSelected(group2[index], group1[index]);
                settings[index].afterChanges();
            });
            $('#' + settings[index].allTo1).click(function () {
                MoveAll(group2[index], group1[index]);
                settings[index].afterChanges();
            });
        } else {
            $('#' + group2[index].view).dblclick(function () {
                RemoveSelected(group2[index], group1[index]);
            }); $('#' + settings[index].to1).click(function () {
                RemoveSelected(group2[index], group1[index]);
            }); $('#' + settings[index].allTo1).click(function () {
                RemoveAll(group2[index], group1[index]);
            });
        }
        $('#' + group1[index].view).dblclick(function () {
            MoveSelected(group1[index], group2[index]);
            settings[index].afterChanges();
        });
        $('#' + settings[index].to2).click(function () {
            MoveSelected(group1[index], group2[index]);
            settings[index].afterChanges();
        });
        $('#' + settings[index].allTo2).click(function () {
            MoveAll(group1[index], group2[index]);
            settings[index].afterChanges();
        }); if (settings[index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(group1[index]);
            UpdateLabel(group2[index]);
        } if (settings[index].useSorting) {
            SortOptions(group1[index]);
            SortOptions(group2[index]);
        }
        $('#' + group1[index].storage + ',#' + group2[index].storage).css('display', 'none');
        if (settings[index].selectOnSubmit) {
            $('#' + settings[index].box2View).closest('form').submit(function () {
                $('#' + settings[index].box2View).children('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
            });
        }
    };
    function UpdateLabel(group) {
        var showingCount = $("#" + group.view + " option").size();
        var hiddenCount = $("#" + group.storage + " option").size();
        $("#" + group.counter).text('Showing ' + showingCount + ' of ' + (showingCount + hiddenCount));
    }
    function Filter(group) {
        var index = group.index;
        var filterLower;
        if (settings[index].useFilters) {
            filterLower = $('#' + group.filter).val().toString().toLowerCase();
        } else {
            filterLower = '';
        } $('#' + group.view + ' option').filter(function (i) {
            var toMatch = $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase();
            return toMatch.indexOf(filterLower) == -1;
        }).appendTo('#' + group.storage);
        $('#' + group.storage + ' option').filter(function (i) {
            var toMatch = $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase();
            return toMatch.indexOf(filterLower) != -1;
        }).appendTo('#' + group.view);
        try {
            $('#' + group.view + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        if (settings[index].useSorting) {
            SortOptions(group);
        } if (settings[index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(group);
        }
    }
    function SortOptions(group) {
        var $toSortOptions = $('#' + group.view + ' option');
        $toSortOptions.sort(onSort[group.index]);
        $('#' + group.view).empty().append($toSortOptions);
    }
    function MoveSelected(fromGroup, toGroup) {
        if (IsMoveMode(settings[fromGroup.index])) {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:selected').appendTo('#' + toGroup.view);
        } else {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:selected:not([class*=copiedOption])').clone().appendTo('#' + toGroup.view).end().end().addClass('copiedOption');
        } try {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option,#' + toGroup.view + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        Filter(toGroup);
        if (settings[fromGroup.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(fromGroup);
        }
    }
    function MoveAll(fromGroup, toGroup) {
        if (IsMoveMode(settings[fromGroup.index])) {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option').appendTo('#' + toGroup.view);
        } else {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:not([class*=copiedOption])').clone().appendTo('#' + toGroup.view).end().end().addClass('copiedOption');
        }
        try {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option,#' + toGroup.view + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        Filter(toGroup);
        if (settings[fromGroup.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(fromGroup);
        }
    }
    function RemoveSelected(removeGroup, otherGroup) {
        $('#' + otherGroup.view + ' option.copiedOption').add('#' + otherGroup.storage + ' option.copiedOption').remove();
        try {
            $('#' + removeGroup.view + ' option:selected').appendTo('#' + otherGroup.view).removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        $('#' + removeGroup.view + ' option').add('#' + removeGroup.storage + ' option').clone().addClass('copiedOption').appendTo('#' + otherGroup.view);
        Filter(otherGroup);
        if (settings[removeGroup.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(removeGroup);
        }
    }
    function RemoveAll(removeGroup, otherGroup) {
        $('#' + otherGroup.view + ' option.copiedOption').add('#' + otherGroup.storage + ' option.copiedOption').remove();
        try {
            $('#' + removeGroup.storage + ' option').clone().addClass('copiedOption').add('#' + removeGroup.view + ' option').appendTo('#' + otherGroup.view).removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        Filter(otherGroup);
        if (settings[removeGroup.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(removeGroup);
        }
    }
    function ClearFilter(group) {
        $('#' + group.filter).val('');
        $('#' + group.storage + ' option').appendTo('#' + group.view);
        try {
            $('#' + group.view + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        if (settings[group.index].useSorting) {
            SortOptions(group);
        } if (settings[group.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(group);
        }
    }
    function IsMoveMode(currSettings) {
        return currSettings.transferMode == 'move';
    }
    
})(jQuery);
```

Em minha View, sobreponho essa função realizando validações, onde existe uma regra:

> Só é permitido selecionar um item por tipo.

Caso contrário o item volta para a primeira caixa de seleção.

```
$.configureBoxes({
            useCounters: false,
            useSorting: false,
            afterChanges: function () {

                var itens = [];
                var tipos= [];

                $("#box2View").find("option").each(function () {
                    var item = parseInt($(this).val());
                    var tipo= $(this).data("tipo");

                    if ($.inArray(tipo, tipos) >= 0) {
                        alert("Tipos Iguais!");

                        Reverse();
                    } else {
                        itens.push(item);
                        tipos.push(tipo);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Meu problema é com a função `Reverse` que eu gostaria que ficasse no plugin, mas como estou sobrepondo a função `afterChanges` na View, então não consigo acessar a função `Reverse`, e por isso não sei onde devo coloca-la.

Função `Reverse`:

```
function Reverse() {
            var removeGroup = group1[index];
            var otherGroup = group2[index];

            $('#' + otherGroup.view + ' option.copiedOption').add('#' + otherGroup.storage + ' option.copiedOption').remove();
            try {
                $('#' + removeGroup.view + ' option:selected').appendTo('#' + otherGroup.view).removeAttr('selected');
            } catch (ex) { }
            $('#' + removeGroup.view + ' option').add('#' + removeGroup.storage + ' option').clone().addClass('copiedOption').appendTo('#' + otherGroup.view);
            Filter(otherGroup);
            if (settings[removeGroup.index].useCounters) {
                UpdateLabel(removeGroup);
            }
        }
```

Como faço para deixar a função `Reverse` acessível na View?

Onde devo coloca-la no plugin?

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Resolvi, fiz uma modificação na biblioteca, ainda hoje vou tentar postar a resposta aqui.

Comment: A Comunidade agradece.

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Resposta feita!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver meu problema foi necessário modificar a biblioteca.

A mesma ficou da seguinte forma:

```js
/*
*       Developed by Justin Mead
*       ©2011 MeadMiracle
*  www.meadmiracle.com / meadmiracle@gmail.com
*       Version 1.3
*       Testing: IE8/Windows XP
*                Firefox/Windows XP
*                Chrome/Windows XP
*       Licensed under the Creative Commons GPL http://creativecommons.org/licenses/GPL/2.0/
*/

(function ($) {
    var settings = new Array();
    var group1 = new Array();
    var group2 = new Array();
    var onSort = new Array();
    $.configureBoxes = function (options) {
        var index = settings.push({
            box1View: 'box1View',
            box1Storage: 'box1Storage',
            box1Filter: 'box1Filter',
            box1Clear: 'box1Clear',
            box1Counter: 'box1Counter',
            box2View: 'box2View',
            box2Storage: 'box2Storage',
            box2Filter: 'box2Filter',
            box2Clear: 'box2Clear',
            box2Counter: 'box2Counter',
            to1: 'to1',
            allTo1: 'allTo1',
            to2: 'to2',
            allTo2: 'allTo2',
            transferMode: 'move',
            sortBy: 'text',
            useFilters: true,
            useCounters: true,
            useSorting: true,
            selectOnSubmit: true,
            enableValidation: false,
            afterChanges: function (toGroup, toGroupIsMoveMode) { },
            validation: function (to1destined, allGroupdestined, fromGroup, toGroup, fromGroupIsMoveMode, toGroupIsMoveMode) { return true }
        })
        index--;
        $.extend(settings[index], options);
        group1.push({
            view: settings[index].box1View,
            storage: settings[index].box1Storage,
            filter: settings[index].box1Filter,
            clear: settings[index].box1Clear,
            counter: settings[index].box1Counter,
            index: index
        });
        group2.push({
            view: settings[index].box2View,
            storage: settings[index].box2Storage,
            filter: settings[index].box2Filter,
            clear: settings[index].box2Clear,
            counter: settings[index].box2Counter,
            index: index
        });
        if (settings[index].sortBy == 'text') {
            onSort.push(function (a, b) {
                var aVal = a.text.toLowerCase();
                var bVal = b.text.toLowerCase();
                if (aVal < bVal) { return -1; }
                if (aVal > bVal) { return 1; } return 0;
            });
        } else {
            onSort.push(function (a, b) {
                var aVal = a.value.toLowerCase();
                var bVal = b.value.toLowerCase();
                if (aVal < bVal) { return -1; }
                if (aVal > bVal) { return 1; } return 0;
            });
        } if (settings[index].useFilters) {
            $('#' + group1[index].filter).keyup(function () {
                Filter(group1[index]);
            });
            $('#' + group2[index].filter).keyup(function () {
                Filter(group2[index]);
            });
            $('#' + group1[index].clear).click(function () {
                ClearFilter(group1[index]);
            }); $('#' + group2[index].clear).click(function () {
                ClearFilter(group2[index]);
            });
        } if (IsMoveMode(settings[index])) {
            $('#' + group2[index].view).dblclick(function () {
                if ((!settings[index].enableValidation) || (settings[index].enableValidation && settings[index].validation(to1destined = true, allGroupdestined = false, group1[index], group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group1[index].index]), IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index])))) {
                    MoveSelected(group2[index], group1[index]);
                    settings[index].afterChanges(group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index]));
                }
            });
            $('#' + settings[index].to1).click(function () {
                if ((!settings[index].enableValidation) || (settings[index].enableValidation && settings[index].validation(to1destined = true, allGroupdestined = false, group1[index], group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group1[index].index]), IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index])))) {
                    MoveSelected(group2[index], group1[index]);
                    settings[index].afterChanges(group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index]));
                }
            });
            $('#' + settings[index].allTo1).click(function () {
                if ((!settings[index].enableValidation) || (settings[index].enableValidation && settings[index].validation(to1destined = true, allGroupdestined = true, group1[index], group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group1[index].index]), IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index])))) {
                    MoveAll(group2[index], group1[index]);
                    settings[index].afterChanges(group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index]));
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#' + group2[index].view).dblclick(function () {
                RemoveSelected(group2[index], group1[index]);
            }); $('#' + settings[index].to1).click(function () {
                RemoveSelected(group2[index], group1[index]);
            }); $('#' + settings[index].allTo1).click(function () {
                RemoveAll(group2[index], group1[index]);
            });
        }
        $('#' + group1[index].view).dblclick(function () {
            if ((!settings[index].enableValidation) || (settings[index].enableValidation && settings[index].validation(to1destined = false, allGroupdestined = false, group1[index], group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group1[index].index]), IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index])))) {
                MoveSelected(group1[index], group2[index]);
                settings[index].afterChanges(group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index]));
            }
        });
        $('#' + settings[index].to2).click(function () {
            if ((!settings[index].enableValidation) || (settings[index].enableValidation && settings[index].validation(to1destined = false, allGroupdestined = false, group1[index], group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group1[index].index]), IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index])))) {
                MoveSelected(group1[index], group2[index]);
                settings[index].afterChanges(group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index]));
            }
        });
        $('#' + settings[index].allTo2).click(function () {
            if ((!settings[index].enableValidation) || (settings[index].enableValidation && settings[index].validation(to1destined = false, allGroupdestined = true, group1[index], group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group1[index].index]), IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index])))) {
                MoveAll(group1[index], group2[index]);
                settings[index].afterChanges(group2[index], IsMoveMode(settings[group2[index].index]));
            }
        }); if (settings[index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(group1[index]);
            UpdateLabel(group2[index]);
        } if (settings[index].useSorting) {
            SortOptions(group1[index]);
            SortOptions(group2[index]);
        }
        $('#' + group1[index].storage + ',#' + group2[index].storage).css('display', 'none');
        if (settings[index].selectOnSubmit) {
            $('#' + settings[index].box2View).closest('form').submit(function () {
                $('#' + settings[index].box2View).children('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
            });
        }
    };
    function UpdateLabel(group) {
        var showingCount = $("#" + group.view + " option").size();
        var hiddenCount = $("#" + group.storage + " option").size();
        $("#" + group.counter).text('Showing ' + showingCount + ' of ' + (showingCount + hiddenCount));
    }
    function Filter(group) {
        var index = group.index;
        var filterLower;
        if (settings[index].useFilters) {
            filterLower = $('#' + group.filter).val().toString().toLowerCase();
        } else {
            filterLower = '';
        } $('#' + group.view + ' option').filter(function (i) {
            var toMatch = $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase();
            return toMatch.indexOf(filterLower) == -1;
        }).appendTo('#' + group.storage);
        $('#' + group.storage + ' option').filter(function (i) {
            var toMatch = $(this).text().toString().toLowerCase();
            return toMatch.indexOf(filterLower) != -1;
        }).appendTo('#' + group.view);
        try {
            $('#' + group.view + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        if (settings[index].useSorting) {
            SortOptions(group);
        } if (settings[index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(group);
        }
    }
    function SortOptions(group) {
        var $toSortOptions = $('#' + group.view + ' option');
        $toSortOptions.sort(onSort[group.index]);
        $('#' + group.view).empty().append($toSortOptions);
    }
    function MoveSelected(fromGroup, toGroup) {
        if (IsMoveMode(settings[fromGroup.index])) {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:selected').appendTo('#' + toGroup.view);
        } else {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:selected:not([class*=copiedOption])').clone().appendTo('#' + toGroup.view).end().end().addClass('copiedOption');
        } try {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option,#' + toGroup.view + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        Filter(toGroup);
        if (settings[fromGroup.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(fromGroup);
        }
    }
    function MoveAll(fromGroup, toGroup) {
        if (IsMoveMode(settings[fromGroup.index])) {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option').appendTo('#' + toGroup.view);
        } else {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:not([class*=copiedOption])').clone().appendTo('#' + toGroup.view).end().end().addClass('copiedOption');
        }
        try {
            $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option,#' + toGroup.view + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        Filter(toGroup);
        if (settings[fromGroup.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(fromGroup);
        }
    }
    function RemoveSelected(removeGroup, otherGroup) {
        $('#' + otherGroup.view + ' option.copiedOption').add('#' + otherGroup.storage + ' option.copiedOption').remove();
        try {
            $('#' + removeGroup.view + ' option:selected').appendTo('#' + otherGroup.view).removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        $('#' + removeGroup.view + ' option').add('#' + removeGroup.storage + ' option').clone().addClass('copiedOption').appendTo('#' + otherGroup.view);
        Filter(otherGroup);
        if (settings[removeGroup.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(removeGroup);
        }
    }
    function RemoveAll(removeGroup, otherGroup) {
        $('#' + otherGroup.view + ' option.copiedOption').add('#' + otherGroup.storage + ' option.copiedOption').remove();
        try {
            $('#' + removeGroup.storage + ' option').clone().addClass('copiedOption').add('#' + removeGroup.view + ' option').appendTo('#' + otherGroup.view).removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        Filter(otherGroup);
        if (settings[removeGroup.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(removeGroup);
        }
    }
    function ClearFilter(group) {
        $('#' + group.filter).val('');
        $('#' + group.storage + ' option').appendTo('#' + group.view);
        try {
            $('#' + group.view + ' option').removeAttr('selected');
        } catch (ex) { }
        if (settings[group.index].useSorting) {
            SortOptions(group);
        } if (settings[group.index].useCounters) {
            UpdateLabel(group);
        }
    }
    function IsMoveMode(currSettings) {
        return currSettings.transferMode == 'move';
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Criei 3 novas propriedades:

- **enableValidation**: *Boolean* - Por padrão vem *false*, mas quanto *true* habilita o uso da segunda propriedade (função) para realizar uma validação antes de transferir o item.
- **validation**: *Function* - Quando **enableValidation** está *true* a função criada para essa propriedade é executada antes de mover o item selecionado. É importante dizer que a função criada para essa propriedade deve retornar um Boolean (true ou false) para mover o item caso seja válido.
- **afterChanges**: *Function* - Quando um item é movido esta função é executada. Não precisa retornar nada.

Exemplo de uso:

```js
$.configureBoxes({
            useCounters: false,
            useSorting: false,
            enableValidation: true, // Habilitando validação
            afterChanges: function (toGroup, toGroupIsMoveMode) {

                // Obtendo itens que foram movidos da caixa1 para a caixa2:
                var toGroupItens = new Object();

                if (toGroupIsMoveMode) {
                    toGroupItens = $('#' + toGroup.view + ' option');
                } else {
                    toGroupItens = $('#' + toGroup.view + ' option:not([class*=copiedOption])')
                }

                // Continue aqui com os itens já em mãos...

            },
            validation: function (to1destined, allGroupdestined, fromGroup, toGroup, fromGroupIsMoveMode, toGroupIsMoveMode) {
                // Itens não são destinados para caixa1? (ou seja, itens são destinados para caixa2?)
                if (!to1destined) {

                    // Obtendo itens:
                    var fromGroupItens = new Object();
                    var toGroupItens = new Object();

                    if (allGroupdestined) {
                        if (fromGroupIsMoveMode) {
                            fromGroupItens = $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option');
                        } else {
                            fromGroupItens = $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:not([class*=copiedOption])')
                        }

                        if (toGroupIsMoveMode) {
                            toGroupItens = $('#' + toGroup.view + ' option');
                        } else {
                            toGroupItens = $('#' + toGroup.view + ' option:not([class*=copiedOption])')
                        }

                        // Obtendo tipos dos itens
                        var fromGroupItensArray = [],
                            ocurrence = 0;

                        fromGroupItens.each(function () {
                            fromGroupItensArray.push(parseInt($(this).data("tipo")));
                        });

                        fromGroupItens.each(function () {
                            var target = parseInt($(this).data("tipo"));
                            var numOccurences = $.grep(fromGroupItensArray, function (elem) {
                                return elem === target;
                            }).length;
                            if (numOccurences > 1) {
                                ocurrence++;
                            }
                        });

                        if (ocurrence != 0) {
                            alert("Erro de validação!");
                            return false;
                        }

                        var toGroupItensArray = [],
                            ocurrence = 0;

                        toGroupItens.each(function () {
                            var elem = parseInt($(this).data("tipo"));
                            toGroupItensArray.push(elem);
                        });

                        fromGroupItens.each(function () {
                            var target = parseInt($(this).data("tipo"));
                            if ($.inArray(target, toGroupItensArray) >= 0) {
                                ocurrence++;
                            }
                        });

                        if (ocurrence == 0) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            alert("Erro de validação!");
                            return false;
                        }


                    } else {
                        if (fromGroupIsMoveMode) {
                            fromGroupItens = $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:selected');
                        } else {
                            fromGroupItens = $('#' + fromGroup.view + ' option:selected:not([class*=copiedOption])');
                        }

                        if (toGroupIsMoveMode) {
                            toGroupItens = $('#' + toGroup.view + ' option');
                        } else {
                            toGroupItens = $('#' + toGroup.view + ' option:not([class*=copiedOption])');
                        }

                        var fromGroupItensArray = [],
                           ocurrence = 0;

                        fromGroupItens.each(function () {
                            fromGroupItensArray.push(parseInt($(this).data("tipo")));
                        });

                        fromGroupItens.each(function () {
                            var target = parseInt($(this).data("tipo"));
                            var numOccurences = $.grep(fromGroupItensArray, function (elem) {
                                return elem === target;
                            }).length;
                            if (numOccurences > 1) {
                                ocurrence++;
                            }
                        });

                        if (ocurrence != 0) {
                            alert("Erro de validação!");
                            return false;
                        }

                        var toGroupItensArray = [],
                            ocurrence = 0;

                        toGroupItens.each(function () {
                            var elem = parseInt($(this).data("tipo"));
                            toGroupItensArray.push(elem);
                        });

                        fromGroupItens.each(function () {
                            var target = parseInt($(this).data("tipo"));
                            if ($.inArray(target, toGroupItensArray) >= 0) {
                                ocurrence++;
                            }
                        });

                        if (ocurrence == 0) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            alert("Erro de validação!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Marque a resposta como aceita.